# How to modify/change data loaded in the frontmatter in Astro?

Tags: javascript, jsx, astrojs

I am using Astro to build a basic application where I am loading a JSON Array from a file using import syntax in frontmatter. Now I want to split data in half on every click depending which side of the half you have clicked. I have made a demo in [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/jOJqgVL) please check.

I just need to understand how do I load a data in frontMatter from API or local file and modify it. I was using script tag to write my methods to do the operations but I cant seem to access the data in script and also I can't access data from  script tag into my markup.

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';
import Card from "../components/Card.astro";
import messages from '../content/messages_arr.json'; /* <-- frontmatter */
---

<script>
  export let data_A =  "Data A"
  let data_B =  "Data B"
  
  export let methodA = () =>{ console.log(A)}
  let methodB = () =>{ console.log(B)}
  
</script>

<Layout> /* <-- markup */
<div>
  {message}
  {data_A}
  {data_B}
  <button onclick={methodA}>METHOD A</button>
  <button onclick={methodB}>METHOD B</button>
</div>
</Layout>
```

Comment: are you looking for https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#pass-frontmatter-variables-to-scripts ?

Comment: @mb21 I have seen this already. The problem is it is using react like components but I am just working on top of the default projects generated by astro which doesn't have component like this. I know I can use any framework be it vue, react or svelt. My problem is, how would I access the data imported from a file and make changes to it and update in the UI.

Comment: "how would I access the data [...] and make changes to it and update in the UI" – that's exactly the problem that vue, react, svelte and solid solve :-) See e.g. https://astro.new/framework-solid Astro components only run on the server, so you cannot update the GUI in reaction to onClick events or similar without using framework components, script tags (or links to navigate to a new page).

Comment: @mb21 Thank you for the previous link. I should have read the entire description. I am dumb. The frontmatter  code runs on the server and script runs on the client, hence passsing data is not just complicated but wrong in terms of architecture too. As you have mentioned now... I need to use some frame to do so. Thank you once again.

Comment: exactly, good luck!